# Cannot create hamburger using bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a navbar that will become a hamburger when the screen is small....but just cannot figure it out why it didn't work...I put everything inside a collapse tag but still didn't work. Thanks for the time!!

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Prof Yuh-Jong Hu</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="DadWebPage.css">
        <!-- Fonts: Roboto Condensed -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>

      <body>
        <!-- nav-bar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">

            <!-- navbar header -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false">
                <!-- the hamburger -->
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>

              <p id="brandName" class="navbar-text">Matthew</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li class="active"><a href="DadWebPageMain.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Career.html">Career</a></li>
                <li><a href="Projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="Publications.html">Publications</a></li>
                <li><a href="AcademicServices.html">Academic Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="Talks.html">Talks</a></li>
                <li><a href="GraduateStudentsAdvising.html">Graduate Students Advising</a></li>

              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <script src="DadWebPage.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Matthew, I have updated my answer. You must add the necessary JavaScript Libraries (jQuery, and Bootstrap) in order for your navbar to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must insert Bootstrap's Javascript as well as jQuery library for the NavBar to function properly! Add it inside of your `body` tag at the end.

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Nonetheless, all of the information can be found in their [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar) explaining what is required from the `navbar` element.

Questions you may need to ask:

1. Are you including the CSS and Javascript in your page?
2. Are there any console logs indicating an error
3. Ensure that you have meta tag for `viewport`. As that is used to determine the size of your page: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
4. Is JS enabled on your page?

Your page should have looked something like Bootstrap's 101 template - also found in their documentation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <!-- etc... -->
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick apply! I have everything in my html. The problem here is that when the screen becomes smaller, it actually appears a hamburger icon, but when clicking the icon, nothing would happen...

Comment: Do you have any logs in your console? That would indicate as to whether you're running into JS issues

Comment: You can also check and make sure that you are including the jQuery library. You will see an error if the jQuery is not included

Comment: It says: bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6

Comment: Add jQuery before adding bootstrap. Look at the top of my answer... I updated it for you to understand. @MatthewHu

Comment: I got it!!Just solved the problem, thanks a lot Samuel!

Comment: No problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Prof Yuh-Jong Hu</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Fonts: Roboto Condensed -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>

      <body>
        <!-- nav-bar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">

            <!-- navbar header -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false">
                <!-- the hamburger -->
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>

              <p id="brandName" class="navbar-text">Matthew</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li class="active"><a href="DadWebPageMain.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Career.html">Career</a></li>
                <li><a href="Projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="Publications.html">Publications</a></li>
                <li><a href="AcademicServices.html">Academic Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="Talks.html">Talks</a></li>
                <li><a href="GraduateStudentsAdvising.html">Graduate Students Advising</a></li>

              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </body>
    </html>
```

You must add jQuery for collapse class working.